# How to calculate a value to a certain number of decimal places?

Tags: python, floating-accuracy

Using numpy or python's standard library, either or.  How can I take a value with several decimal places and truncate it to 4 decimal places?  I only want to compare floating point numbers to their first 4 decimal points.

Answer (score 6):

round(a_float, 4)

```
>>> help(round)
Help on built-in function round in module __builtin__:

round(...)
    round(number[, ndigits]) -> floating point number

    Round a number to a given precision in decimal digits (default 0 digits).
    This always returns a floating point number.  Precision may be negative.

>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to compare two floats, you can compare on `abs(a-b) < epsilon` where epsilon is your precision requirement.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> round(1.2345678,4) == round(1.2345999,4)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) module, especially the part on `getcontext().prec`